# seo friendly / Clean URLs - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I am totally new to Apache / mod_rewrite. I need to do this

The below URL:

```
http://www.example.com/applications/seo-friendly-text-for-appA/some-random-php-page.php
```

Should display as

```
http://www.example.com/applications/seo-friendly-text-for-appA
```

and redirect to some-random-php-page.php which lies in a folder called "myappAfolder". My web folder structure is as follows:

```
<example-com-webroot>/applications/myappAfolder/some-random-php-page.php
```

And also if I were to do this in the reverse - say if I type the following URL

```
http://www.example.com/applications/myappAfolder/some-random-php-page.php
```

the URL should show as

```
http://www.example.com/applications/seo-friendly-text-for-appA
```

But at the same time redirect to the page which lies in

```
<example-com-webroot>/applications/myappAfolder/some-random-php-page.php
```

I have tried some other solutions mentioned in SO but no luck so far. I've been on this for hours now

P.N: seo-friendly-text-for-appA is not a folder and it does not exist in my web root

Comment: I have no idea which troll down-voted me and for what

Answer (score 0):

You should pass some id for each file, for example

```
http://www.example.com/seo-friendly-text-for-appA ->
http://www.example.com/filename.php?id=seo-friendly-text-for-appA
```

Hope you can write mod_rewrite, there is a lot of examples in the Web. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)$                    /filename.php?id=$1
```

I think the best way for reverse is php, not mod_rewrite.

Comment: I know it's possible without changing my URLs and sending arbitrary IDs. And the reverse is possible too, just by using htaccess. I'll post it as soon as I get some leads. It's just that I don't want to do it the wrong way. Thanks anyway